# Create scenario(for business side) like serenity jbehave on karatedsl

Tags: karate, scenarios

The purpose of my question is I want to create scenario on karatedsl like on serenity and jbehave, is it possible to make this on karatedsl ??
so, even though someone who don't understand our system can easily understand about our system through scenario..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Karate how we can collaboratively work along with BA to automate business scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795762/in-karate-how-we-can-collaboratively-work-along-with-ba-to-automate-business-sce)