# integrating TM4J (Test management for Jira) Adpavist with Karate Tests

Tags: karate, cucumber-jvm, jira-integration

Does Karate API tests supports integration with TM4J (Test management for Jira - Adaptavist)?
We have been using Karate for our GraphQL layer and it has been quite successful so far. we have a requirement to integrate TM4J across multiple frameworks across the company and hence wanted to know if it is possible?

TM4J supports cucumber.options

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Karate exports the cucumber-json, this may work without any change.

Also refer this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

And note that Karate does one thing slightly differently, so you may need to be aware of that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56516016/143475

Anything beyond this we consider the responsibility of the external tool side, or you have to write a custom-hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas

Comment: we are using Karate 0.9.5 with Karate options in the runner file and we are looking to integrate with TM4J(Test management for Jira) and TM4J expects a plugin in the runner file and with the Karate.option i don't seem to have the ability to pass the plugin ... can you please advise on what is best way forward for integrating TM4J with Karate 0.9.5 version ... Thanks

Comment: @AnilKumarNagisetty I have nothing to add other than the links above which will give you hints on how to write an extension / integration which may be needed. Karate is **NOT** Cucumber.

Comment: Thanks for that @Peter