# Can we write tests in visual studio by using karate library?

Tags: karate

Does Karate support integrating into visual studio? As we are all writing automated api tests in visual studio using SpecFlow, we would like to continue visual studio with karate if it supports.
Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really shouldn't matter. Karate works over HTTP, we have many JS, Python and .NET teams using Karate. You have the option of a stand-alone JAR also that will work in CI, see this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

That said, we have [Visual Studio Code support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner).

You should also read this other answer on SO, I think it is especially relevant for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475