# How do I define my own StepActions class in a Karate test?

Tags: karate

How do I define my own StepActions class in a Karate test?

All I need is one working example (apparently nobody has an example of this anywhere; I looked and couldn't find anything and so I am asking here).

For example, how would I implement this helper step action in Java?   In this case, how do I get access to the WebDriver `driver` instance from within Java context?  Then, how do I call the embed?

```
@Slf4j
public class SeleniumStepActions extends StepActions {
    public SeleniumStepActions(FeatureContext featureContext, CallContext callContext, Scenario scenario, LogAppender appender) {
        super(featureContext, callContext, scenario, appender);
    }
    @When("^screenshot$")
    public void takeAScreenShot()
    {
        // goals is to simulate this in a karate js test
        //    * def bytes = driver.screenshot()
        //    * karate.embed(bytes, 'image/png')
        log.info("Testing my own custom action.");
    }
}
```

It is possible the above won't work.  I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction by someone who knows.   I wish there was such an example in the karate demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

For a detailed discussion, please read this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/398

The summary:

- Karate does not support the "Step Definitions" that Cucumber does
- There are 2 ways to inject custom logic, a) JS, b) Java interop
- These are more than sufficient to implement something close to custom "keywords" - see this example: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1128170638223364097
- and another: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1144458169822806016

If you insist on making your test read like "plain english" (which IMHO [is not worth it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475)) - then Karate may not be the best choice for your team.

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't seen any of those links.  I appreciate it.