# How to integrate both karate and cucumber and invoke both from a single file/class

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I created cucumber automation code for a project, How to call karate feature files from cucumber runner class, or any other way to run the karate feature files from cucumber framework, My plan is to integrate both karate and cucumber and invoke both from a single file/class

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class TestRunner_Cucumber {

}

Comment: Your idea to mix non-BDD Karate Gherkin with BDD-Cucumber Gherkin, is not a good one, in my opinion.  Keep them separate.

Comment: I think you would see step undefined warning for karate if you keep both cucumber and karate tests in a single feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Do this using the Java API.  Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api

```
Map<String, Object> result = Runner.runFeature("classpath:demo/java/from-java.feature", args, true);
```

By the way, I don't recommend BDD for API testing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475