# How to resolve com.intuit.karate.KarateException while calling karate feature file from cucumber framework

Tags: cucumber, karate

I can able to call sample karate feature file from cucumber framework. But when I try to call some post request I got the following exception.

com.intuit.karate.KarateException: Could not initialize class com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils

I followed this link [How to integrate both karate and cucumber and invoke both from a single file/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854039/how-to-integrate-both-karate-and-cucumber-and-invoke-both-from-a-single-file-cla/77234764?noredirect=1#comment136160215_77234764)

Could you please guide me how to resolve this?

Comment: sounds like your dependencies for karate are wrong. note that karate is NOT cucumber. please follow this process so others can replicate the problem: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue