# How to use gherkin localization in Karate framework?

Tags: localization, cucumber, karate, gherkin

I want to use [gherkin localization](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/gherkin/gherkin-languages.json) in Karate Framework.

English version of scenario works perfect. But with Russian version it looks like Karate FeatureParser doesn't know localized tags and fails. Here is the error log:

```
line 15:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
16:44:01.263 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
16:44:01.270 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: src/test/java/ru.feature - mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser.<init>(FeatureParser.java:150)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser.<init>(FeatureParser.java:126)
    at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser.parse(FeatureParser.java:69)
    at com.intuit.karate.IdeUtils.exec(IdeUtils.java:61)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

English version of feature file:

```
Feature: Services A and B
  Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:8080'

  Scenario: call service A
    Given path 'service-a'
    And method get
    Then status 200

  Scenario: call service B
    Given path 'service-b'
    And method get
    Then status 200
```

Russian version of feature file:

```
# language: ru
Функция: Сервисы А и Б
  Контекст:
    * адрес 'http://localhost:8080'

  Сценарий: вызов сервиса А
    Дано путь 'service-a'
    И метод get
    То статус 200

  Сценарий: вызов сервиса B
    Дано путь 'service-b'
    И метод get
    То статус 200
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Karate does not support localization after we [switched away from Cucumber](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444#issuecomment-419852761) in version 0.9.0.

We decided not to support localization because the goals of Karate are very different from Cucumber. Karate is more like a programming language, better explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475

So just like Java or JavaScript do not support localized keywords, Karate does not either. [We haven't had any complaints so far :)](https://qiita.com/takanorig/items/5f63806219ae30a8f09a#%E3%83%A2%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)