# Can we create a feature level or global variable in cucumber feature files (java)

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there any way to create a common variable at the feature file level & use it across scenarios instead of hardcoding as below for each step in cucumber feature files using java

```
eg:
Feature: Test
Scenario: scenario 1
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to "url"
  Then response code is 200

Scenario: scenario 2
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to "url"
  Then response code is 200
```

Want to do something like this

```
eg:
Feature: Test
global_variable_url=url
Scenario: scenario 1
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to "<global_variable_url>"
  Then response code is 200

Scenario: scenario 2
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to "<global_variable_url>"
  Then response code is 200
```

Comment: If you're testing http calls and response codes cucumber might not be the right tool. Or you've written the scenario with too much detail.  https://www.gregbeech.com/2014/01/19/effective-api-testing-with-cucumber/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Background](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) keyword that is used to set up the common state for all scenarios like.

```
Feature: Test

Background:
  Given base url "http://my.base/url"

Scenario: scenario 1
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to base url
  Then response code is 200

Scenario: scenario 2
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to base url
  Then response code is 200
```

When you process `Given` step from your `Background` you set the shared reference to that url value and use it from other steps.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a variable across different scenarios is not a good practice as scenarios should be independent and this would being a risk to impact result of one scenario from another one.

That being said, you can preferrably use a `Background` step which defines the value you want to share and use it within your `When` steps:

```
Feature: Test

Background:
  Given the global url is "..."

Scenario: scenario 1
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to global url
  Then response code is 200

Scenario: scenario 2
  Given a user
  When get request is sent to global url
  Then response code is 200
```

In the code of the `Given the global url is "..."` step, store the value in a class attribute, it will be available during the scenario only but not in other scenarios as a new class will be created.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is supported with [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber). It provides [resource configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html) capability and also a way to use in your feature file or code. With qaf provided `base.url` in [properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_configuration.html) file,  your step can look like

```
When get request is sent to "${base.url}"
```

Furthermore, you can utilize [web-service support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws#qaf-support-ws) which provides ready to use steps (doesn't required to write any code).

```
Scenario: scenario 1
  When user requests '${req.examplereq.get}'
  Then response should have status code 200
```

where `req.examplereq.get` represents request call in properties file, may look like below:

**myservice-request-calls.properties**

```
#request call repository for my-service.
req.examplereq.get={\
'headers':{},\
'endPoint':'/myservice-endpoint',\
'baseUrl':'${env.baseurl}',\
'method':'GET',\
'query-parameters':{\
  'param1':'val1',\
  'param2':'val2'\
 },\
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Cucumber I recommend you evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate). Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer.

Karate was created to solve the problems you run in-to when you use Cucumber or REST-assured (or *especially* both combined) - for API testing. To specifically answer this question, you can [declare a variable globally](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configuration) or in the [`Background`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#hooks) for an entire `Feature`. JSON and JS expression support is "built-in". You can even re-use other `Feature` files, which is not possible in Cucumber.

```
Feature:

Background:
* def payload = { hello: 'world' }

Scenario:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/post'
* request payload
* method post
* status 200
* match response.json == payload
```

There are many teams that have fallen into this trap of using Cucumber for API testing because of blog posts by influential yet mis-informed bloggers etc. I humbly request those who read this answer to keep an open-mind and look at the evidence.

BDD is *not* recommended for API testing. You need a lower-level framework, but something that still can be "readable" (to some extend) by business users.

For more information, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475