# karate dsl not support gherking lenguage spanish

Tags: karate

Can i write gherkin (Feature file) in spanish with karate dsl?

Example:

[image]

When I run this it shows me the following error:

[image]

[image]

is just a question,

karate dsl support gherking lenguage spanish  or i need english lenguaje ever ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Karate supports only the English keywords. Please read this to understand why Karate is NOT a BDD framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475

There are many teams across the world who use Karate in different languages because you can add comments that will appear in the report.

Here is an example in Japanese: https://acro-engineer.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/03/02/120000

More examples can be found [here](https://qiita.com/ihgs/items/00da3b05bef5ad9f947f) and [here](https://note.com/shift_tech/n/n2588d2826f60).

[image]